# How do I match certain characters from a certain part of string with a regex?

Tags: regex

I have some urls that look like this:

```
http://subdomain_domain_com/some_path

http://subdomain_domain_com/?some_var=some_value
```

How do I write a regex to match the underscores only from the domain?

PS: I'm using the regex engine in ruby 1.8.7

Comment: The second example is an invalid URI. It should include slash: `http://subdomain_domain_com/?some_var=some_value`

Comment: The validity of the urls is not an issue here, I just want to know how can I match the underscores from the domain. For this particular example I guess you could say I want to match any underscores contained between 2 forward-slashes

Comment: Right, but if you know that there is a slash for sure, it simplifies the Regex.

Comment: Can't you relate just to the first two matches?

Comment: I don't always know for sure that there are only 2 underscores in there

Comment: Could there be a URL like `http://some_domain_com/path_1/path_2/?var=value`? I. e. cases in which "matching between two slashes" would not be correct?

Comment: yeah, those could happend too.

Comment: OK, so this means you can only do this with regex if your regex engine supports arbitrary-length lookbehind assertions. This is only the case for .NET languages (and JGSoft products) as far as I know. Which regex engine are you using? (The regex FAQ asks to always include this information in a regex question)

Comment: I'm using the regex engine in ruby 1.8.7 which I don't think suppports arbitrary-length lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex (based on the exception I wrote in the comment about the URI):

```
(?<=https?://).*(?=/)
```

It covers both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: The OP mentions something about matching underscores.

Comment: Yeah, I believe he meant matching the whole fragment of the domain name rather than the fragment(s) after. I don't believe he meant he just wanted underscore character matches.

Comment: Actually I want only the underscores matched

Comment: How? What do you want your output to be? Underscores? Groups of underscores? Give an example of an output you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
https?://(?<underscore>[^/]+)
```

and get group named *underscore*